# Views not updating using cubit

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I've two tables. on left tables row click I've to update all data that are in table 2.
Code snippets

```
MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider<TableACubit>(
      create: (context) => TableACubit()..getData(a, b),
    ),
    BlocProvider<TableBCubit>(
      create: (context) => TableBCubit(),
    ),
  ],
  child: TableAState(task: task,),
);
```

```
BlocBuilder<TaskCubit, TaskState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      switch (state.status) {
        case AllDataStatus.failure:
          return const Center(child: Text('Oops something went wrong!'));
        case AllDataStatus.success:
         // 2nd tables
          return FDView(
            taskData: state.taskDetails,
            isExpanded: isExpanded,
            keyTile: keyTile,
          );
        default:
          return Loader();
      }
    }
  ),
```

For row click

```
final allData = BlocProvider.of<TaskCubit>(context);
allData.getTasks(task.id!);
```

STATE

```
enum TaskStatus { loading, success, failure }

class TaskState extends Equatable {
  final TaskStatus status;
  Task? task;

  TaskState({
    this.status = AllDataStatus.loading,
    this.task,
  });
  AllDataState.loading() : this();

  AllDataState.success(Task task) : this(status: AllDataStatus.success, task: task);

  AllDataState.failure() : this(status: AllDataStatus.failure);

  /// Need to change here from my previous code
  ///List<Object> get props => [];
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [task];
}
```

Thus the secod tables data aren't reloading while getting new data from table 1's rowclick.
How to refresh the second tables widget after getting new data?

Comment: It show an error ?

Comment: No. ther's no error

Comment: Got the issue. Need to change into props from   ```@override
  List<Object?> get props => []; ``` to ```  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [task];```

Comment: Can you add in your post the TaskCubit and TaskState ?

Comment: I've updated my state. Miss to empty the task times. Now it's working fine.